# How to detect if a user received new apprequest

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to detect if a user receives an apprequest during being in my app's canvas. Is this possible via FB.Event.subscribe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.Event.subscribe has no function for that as [facebook described](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). But you can accomplish it with [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).